# react-runner causing infinite re-renders

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to use `react-runner`(https://github.com/nihgwu/react-runner) to display my components, but the function they provide, `useRunner` creates an infinite render loop the moment I add the scope, even as an empty object.

This is my current code, where I am only returning a title to prove the error wasn't in the components:

```js
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Scope, useRunner, importCode } from "react-runner";
import { CodeEditor } from "react-live-runner";
import * as draftjs from "draft-js";
// raw-loader imports the context of a file as text
import Helpers from "!!raw-loader!./common/Helpers.ts";
import common from "!!raw-loader!./common/Definitions.ts";
import MyTextBox from "!!raw-loader!./mytextbox/MyTextBox.tsx";

const textBox = `
import MyTextBox from "./MyTextBox";
<MyTextBox />`;

export default function App() {
    createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <UseRunnerMyTextBox code={textBox} transformCode={undefined} />
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}

const isString = (element: any) => (typeof element === "string" ? element : "");

function UseRunnerMyTextBox({
    code: initialCode,
    transformCode
}: RunnerProps) {
    const result = useRunner({
        code: transformCode ? transformCode(initialCode) : initialCode,
        scope: {
            import: {
                "./MyTextBox": importCode(isString(MyTextBox), {
                    import: {
                        react: React,
                        "draft-js": draftjs,
                        "../common/Helpers": importCode(isString(Helpers)),
                        "../common": importCode(isString(common))
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    });

    console.log(result);

    return (
        <h1>Potato</h1>
    );
}
```

This is the implementation of the hook provided by this package: https://github.com/nihgwu/react-runner/blob/974ebc932db7b7c7d59f1b50a79aed705efbf75a/packages/react-runner/src/useRunner.ts

This is the error I get when trying to run the code:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    at UseRunnerAdvancedTextBox (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12228:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:173:5)
```

Does anyone see what could be causing the infinite render? It happens the second I add scope in the useRunner, even if the scope is empty object or if I extract the scope definition outside the hook. But it does seem to be evaluating the scope, once I add the initial import, it will complain about the other missing imports until I add them. The infinite render happens at any point of this process.